# Asyncio and Labeled hrefs

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have some code where I have some hrefs and some accompanying labels.  I need to make sure the labels, hrefs, and response from pulling the hrefs all stay associated, (e,g., a list in a list of lists, a list of tuples, etc.)

Since Asyncio acts asyncronously, if I understand correctly, the gathered results of the pulled hrefs may be returned in a different order than they were sent.  This would mean my rendered pages would be potentially out of sequence with my labels if I try to process after page renderings are returned.  Do I understand this correctly?

Example:

```
href_list = ['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', 'www.amazon.com']
names_list = ['Google','Yahoo','Amazon']
zipped_list = list(zip(href_list,names_list))


async def fetch_href(session, href):
    response = await session.request(method='GET', url=href)
    return await response.text()

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    page_results = await asyncio.gather(*(fetch_href(session, href) 
                                        for i, href in enumerate([item[0] for item in zipped_list])))

    #page_results may have html in a different order than the hrefs and labels in zipped_list
    #because of asyncronous behavior of the function (?) e.g:
    # page_results == [amazon_html, google_html, yahoo_html]

    #if I try to zip with zip_list or components the html results would be out of order with
    #hrefs and labels
```

My understanding is that the elements of `page_results` may not correspond to the order of `hrefs` and `names` in the `zipped_list` because those individual request may be returned in a different order.

What is the best way to keep href, name, and page result all associated with each other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results will actually get returned in the order they were passed to gather. Per the [asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) "The order of result values corresponds to the order of awaitables in aws."

You are correct that your results may arrive in any order, however, the gather method only assembles its results array once all coroutines have finished execution. Once they are finished it assembles the results in the order your coroutines were passed in, thus you'll get website 1 first and website 2 second even if website 2 completed first.